# How do I send data to the pre-generated Asp.net database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2015. I would like to add a first and last name to the already pre-generated Asp.net database. These columns are in the database. I have added on to the RegisterViewModel...

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my controller, which I have barely modified...

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //string EncodedResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];
        //bool IsCaptchaValid=(ReCaptcha.Validate(EncodedResponse)=="True" ? true: false);
        //if (IsCaptchaValid)
        //{
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
        user.LastName = model.LastName;
```

etc... I'm not sure why FirstName and LastName are not getting sent to the database. I thought this was the way to do it, and I have seen other ways, but I am not sure. Once I understand this, and get it to work I should be fine. Thank you.

Comment: You are adding the First and lest name, after you create the user. Move the assignments before `UserManager.CreateAsync`

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller to do this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```